# Check if character equals \ in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to see if a character `c` equals `\`

```
if (c == '\')
 //do something
```

I don't know exactly how this is called but everything after \ turns in a character string.

Comment: Try `'\\'`. '\' is the "escape character", which means "the next character is special". For instance, `'\n'` is a newline character. So to get a normal backslash, you have to escape it, using a backslash. Basically, use 2.

Answer (score 14):

Backslash is used as the escape character in C++, as it is in many other languages. If you want a literal backslash, you need to use `\\`:

```
if (c == '\\') {

}
```

Answer (score 7):

`\` backslash is an escape character.

> Escape sequences are used to represent certain special characters
>   within string literals and character literals.
>   Read [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape)

So you should do:

```
if (c == '\\'){
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need [escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape):

> ```
> \\    backslash   byte 0x5c in ASCII encoding
> ```

Change the code to

```
if (c == '\\')
```